# QGIS 2.8.2 - Using spatial expressions in labelling

Tags: qgis, labeling, intersection, expression

I'm creating some hard copy map output from QGIS.

I want to use an expression to suppress labels for some features on a layer when another feature from another layer intersects with those features.

E.g. I want to suppress labels for river (line) features when they intersect with lake (polygon) features.

From my understanding of the documentation the expression should look something like this in the Layer Properties label dialogue of the 'Rivers' layer:

CASE WHEN  intersects( ( $geometry , geometry(getfeature(Lakes_dams)) = 1 THEN  null  ElSE title( "NAME") END

This is invalid so what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Why you didn't use the label priority? Setting an high priority to lakes and a low one to rivers you should obtain the same result. Using your method there is a problem because if the expression works it will suppress the label for all the river geometry (because probably the river is not cut in correspondence of the lake) so you will not have the river label.

Comment: Tried using priority in the first instance. as for complete suppression, this won't happen as the river geometry comprises multiple poly lines per river feature rather than a single poly line per feature.

Comment: Might this be invalid because of 4 opening and 2 closing brackets?! Does  intersects($geometry, geometry(getfeature(Lakes_dams))) work?

Comment: Thanks Jochen, I tried your suggestion but still invalid. I think I may have to rethink this question again or look at QGIS 2.14.